# How can I read WPF publish version number in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I want to read and display WPF application publish version number in splash windows, In project properties in publish tab there is publish version, how can I get this and display it in WPF windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add reference to `System.Deployment` library to your project and adjust this snippet to your code:

```
using System.Deployment.Application;
```

and

```
string version = null;
try
{   
    //// get deployment version
    version = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
}
catch (InvalidDeploymentException)
{
    //// you cannot read publish version when app isn't installed 
    //// (e.g. during debug)
    version = "not installed";
}
```

As stated in comment, you cannot obtain publish version during debug, so I suggest to handle `InvalidDeploymentException`.

Comment: If you start by checking ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed this will let you know if CurrentDeployment is available. This way you don't have to handle the exception, but can make a simple if-else.

Comment: This answers half of the question, but not the part about displaying it in the WPF display. How do you bind a component to then use this version variable?

Comment: Is this still valid in .net core?

Comment: @hybrid2102 It works well. I used these codes on WPF .NET Core 3.1. I added text, Version 1.1.1.1, to Project -> Properties -> Package Tab -> Package Version. I can get the right string on runtime (includes Debug).

Answer (score 65):

Access the assembly version using [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) and display in UI

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, It works but always set the version 1.0.0.0 although my application version is 1.0.0.158 !

Comment: @AbdusalamElsherif where do you have the version? inside the assemblyinfo?

Comment: Adding the Assembly Information in this way definitely works.

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif, i think this is because you are using this code snippet from another project(another assembly). For example your main Windows-app version is 1.0.2, but your dll-project is 1.0.0.

Comment: AssemblyVersion not working if you deploying using "Publish" method.

Comment: Isn't this the file version and not the package version?

Comment: Using Automatic Versioning can make dealing with version numbers a lot easier.

Answer (score 8):

Use `GetEntryAssembly` rather than `GetExecutingAssembly` to get the version from the current executable rather than from the currently-executing DLL, like so:

```
string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(); 

Console.WriteLine(version);
```

Comment: I don't understand why that  this reply and the reply below described the same answer, but one get +17 but another get -1

Comment: @Smith.Lai because is the same answer, except that 2 years after.

Comment: @Smith.Lai You're right, I've edited the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134308/2288578) to clean it up a bit. It's more valid than this answer, which is just a dupe of the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23459838/2288578).